# Can I do CloseMatch of Defined Parsing grammar?

Tags: pyparsing

I have Defined a grammar

```
column = Word(alphanums + '._`')
stmt = column + Literal("(") + Group(delimitedList( column )) +Literal(")")
```

Now I want to match below query using close match

```
sql = seller(food_type,count(sellers),sum(weight),Earned_money)
```

I do not want to change the grammar defined above. How do I closeMatch given 
functions as a argument

```
result = stmt.parseString(sql)
print result.dump()


def Review(sql):
  stmt = GetGrammer(sql)
  result = stmt.parseString(sql,parseAll=False)
  print result.dump()
```

Where var sql is a procedure of 400-500 lines. So I Am making a Automating code Review part.For This purpose I have written grammar for sql statements.
But it is throwing exceptions Even If there is a small string which is not matching.And It is terminating after that.I want that it should not abort even if exceptions are  Comming Because I know that atleast parsable part is useful for reviewing database queries.
Get Grammar is returning grammar for Procedure and all these are sql statements.

```
def Getgrammar(sql):
  InputParameters = delimitedList( Optional((_in|_out|_inout),'') + column + 
  DataType)
  DeclarativeSyntax = (_declare + column + DataType+';')

  createProcedureStmt = createProcedure + 
  StoredProcedure.setResultsName("Procedure") +
  lpar + 
  Optional(InputParameters.setResultsName("Input"),'') + 
  rpar + 
  Optional(_sql_security_invoker,'').setResultsName("SQLSECURITY") +
   _begin + 
  ZeroOrMore(  DeclarativeSyntax ).setResultsName("Declare") + 
  ZeroOrMore( ( selectStmt|setStmt|ifStmt.setResultsName("IfStmt")|
  callStmt|updateStmt|createStmt|dropStmt|alterStmt|insertStmt
  |deleteStmt|WhileStmt.setResultsName("WhileStmt")|createStmt ) + ';') + 
  _end+Optional(';','')

  return createProcedureStmt
```

Comment: I don't see how CloseMatch applies here. The grammar you have does not match the given string, since you are not accounting for functions as columns. How did you see this as being a use case for CloseMatch?

Comment: I am asking solution to a  problem where our grammar is not defined according to given string.
I am Writing a code Reviewer and  there may be many sql statements that are not matching with our grammar than how to avoid That part to Avoid Exceptions of pyparser so that our Grammar can parse Remaning part of sql statements.

Comment: If you are just searching for matching SQL statements, use `searchString` or `scanString` instead of `parseString`. If I have misunderstood what you are doing then please post a little more context information.

Comment: So `GetGrammer` [sic] returns a more complete parser that can handle the other parts of the procedure - otherwise `parseString` wouldn't work. Hopefully there is something inside `GetGrammer` that defines an expression for a non-sql procedure statement, let's say you call it `non_sql_statement`. Then in those places where you look for `sql_statement`, change it to `sql_statement | SkipTo(non_sql_statement)`. Again, without knowing more about what happens inside `GetGrammer`, that's about as much help as I can be. `CloseMatch` will not work here.